# Как преобразовать строковое представление даты в объект даты?

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата, jquery-ui, datepicker

Есть инпут, в котором пользователь выбирает дату с помощью jquery ui datepicker. Из этого инпута получаю значение даты, представленной в виде строки в формате dd.mm.yy. Нужно сделать калькулятор, который будет рассчитывать другие даты на основании выбранной даты. Но не получается преобразовать полученное значение даты в объект даты. Либо выдается 'invalid date', либо 'NaN', либо выскакивают ошибки not a function. Как преобразовать строку в дату для дальнейших расчетов?

Comment: let [day, month, year] = "12.12.2019".split(".");

Comment: new Date(year, month, day);

Comment: @fixeri `new Date(2019, 12, 12)` -> 12.01.2020

Comment: new Date(year, month-1, day);